# Error 451 in excel VBA (Property let procedure not defined...)

Tags: vba, excel

ive been struggling with this code for a couple of days and I need some help. Disclamer, I very new and hence pretty bad at programing, so if you see some optimizations to be done, feel free to tear my code apart.

So, the thing is I want to conditionally print some specific parts of a lab report depending of some cells have a value. So, if a cell has a value other than 0, that whole row or section would be printed.

Ive found this Union function that allows me to add up the print area, so I decided to dim AreaImp as a variable and keep adding up chunks of the worsheet so at the end it all would be printed.

The thing is that when I try to run the code, it gets me error 451 (Property Let procedure not defined and property Get procedure did not return an object) in the PrintOut line (the last line of code before the End Sub) and I honestly don't know where to look for a solution, as I don't know what is causing it.

```
Sub Imprimir()
 Worksheets("Hemato+Bcas").Activate
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim vShts As Variant
 Dim AreaImp As Variant

 AreaImp = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 6))

 'If hematologia

    vShts = Sheets("Hemato+Bcas").Cells(15, 3)

    If Not IsNumeric(vShts) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If vShts > 0 Then
            AreaImp = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(13, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 6))).Address
        End If
    End If

 'For bioquimicas

    For i = 56 To 73

        vShts = Sheets("Hemato+Bcas").Cells(i, 3)

        If Not IsNumeric(vShts) Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If vShts > 0 Then
                AreaImp = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(52, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(55, 6))).Address
                AreaImp = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6))).Address
                AreaImp = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(74, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(86, 6))).Address
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea(AreaImp).PrintOut

End Sub
```

Anyway, thanks in advance and sorry if your eyes are bleeding by reading this

Comment: Looks like AreaImp should be a range and Set to the worksheet range. Also, I'm unclear on what AreaImp = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(... is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A union is a merge of either contiguous or non contiguous cells. You Set the first range then Set to a union of the first range and a second range.

When you get to assigning the .PageSetup.PrintArea, use the address of the union, not the union as a range object.

```
Sub Imprimir()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vShts As Variant
    Dim AreaImp As Variant


 'If hematologia

    vShts = Worksheets("Hemato+Bcas").Cells(15, 3).Value

    If Not IsNumeric(vShts) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Worksheets("Hemato+Bcas").Activate
        Set AreaImp = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 6))
        If vShts > 0 Then
            Set AreaImp = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(13, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 6)))
        End If
    End If

 'For bioquimicas

    For i = 56 To 73

        vShts = Worksheets("Hemato+Bcas").Cells(i, 3).Value
        Set AreaImp = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(52, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(55, 6)))
        Set AreaImp = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(74, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(86, 6)))

        If Not IsNumeric(vShts) Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If vShts > 0 Then
                Set AreaImp = Union(AreaImp, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6)))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = AreaImp.Address
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut

End Sub
```